# HDD shows as "Untitled" în Disk Utility

Tags: partition, hdd, recovery-hd

I have another HDD problem.
I had a broken enclosure witch was acting really weird. It freezes up the finder at some point and I wasn't able to do anything else but to unplug it so "force eject" witch it seems that it was bad for my hdd.

After a few of those One of my external stop appearing in Finder or anywhere else but shows  as "Untitled" in Disk Utility and cannot be mounted. The name "untitled" wasn't actually the name of the volume I had so I guess something happened there. [image]

I have a bunch of data on it. I've tried "first aid" and everything seems fine, but I still cannot mount that volume.
[image]

I did not tried yet any recovery software, I don't wanna mess anything.

Any suggestion on how to fix that?

Comment: Have you browsed to the /Volumes folder to see if it's there? Cmd+Shift+G in a Finder window, then paste in `/Volumes/`

Comment: @KeirThomas alternatively Cmd-Shift-C should bring up Computer which also displays mounted volumes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix my disk through DiskWarrior5. I had to rebuild the directory and I did it with one click.

I had a similar problem a few months back but because I've tried first a few terminal commands DiskWarrior wasn't able to do a thing but this time it worked.